# Key filter HashMap to parce JSON with Kotlin? Retrofit - GSON

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, gson, retrofit

Suppose you have list of objects like this:

```
{
"weight": {
"imperial": "7  -  10",
"metric": "3 - 5"
},
"id": "abys",
"name": "Abyssinian",
"cfa_url": "http://cfa.org/Breeds/BreedsAB/Abyssinian.aspx",
"vetstreet_url": "http://www.vetstreet.com/cats/abyssinian",
"vcahospitals_url": "https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/cat-breeds/abyssinian",
"temperament": "Active, Energetic, Independent, Intelligent, Gentle",
"origin": "Egypt",
"country_codes": "EG",
"country_code": "EG",
"description": "The Abyssinian is easy to care for, and a joy to have in your home. They’re affectionate cats and love both people and other animals.",
"wikipedia_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyssinian_(cat)",
"hypoallergenic": 0,
"reference_image_id": "0XYvRd7oD",
"image": {
"id": "0XYvRd7oD",
"width": 1204,
"height": 1445,
"url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/0XYvRd7oD.jpg"
}
}
```

The data class would look like this.

```
data class Cat(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val wikipedia_url: String,
    val weight: Weight
    )

data class Weight(
    val imperial: String,
    val metric: String )
```

Now my question is, can you use HashMap and specify the key with a string like "weight" to get all its key-value?
Do you have another way to do this?

Comment: put `val catId: String` inside Weight class. as your FK